# How can I list a stop's directly connected neighbors using GTFS?

Tags: sql, gtfs

Lets say that these statemates are included in GTFS data:

```
1. stop A is connected with stop B and stop C
2. stop B is connected with stop D and stop E
3. stop C is connected with Stop F and stop G
```

Now I want to query all stops, that are directly connected with stop A. The result should be `stop B` and `stop C`.

Are those SQL queries possible with GTFS data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although depending on your application the performance might not be everything you expect.

Following your example, let's call stop A the *origin stop* and stops B and C the *connected stops*. Then to build the set of connected stops, we want to find all the stops that

- Share a trip with the origin stop, and
- On that shared trip are visited either immediately before or immediately after the origin stop.

We can use the `stop_sequence` field of the `stop_times` table to test the second condition. Try this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT stops.id, stops.code, stops.name
  FROM stop_times AS origin_stop
  INNER JOIN stop_times AS connected_stops
    ON connected_stops.trip_id = origin_stop.trip_id
      AND ABS(connected_stops.stop_sequence - origin_stop.stop_sequence) = 1
  INNER JOIN stops
    ON stops.id = connected_stops.stop_id
  WHERE origin_stop.stop_id = <origin stop ID>;
```

This joins the `stops` table for a prettier view; if all your application cares about are the connected stops' IDs you can remove that join and change the first line to simply "`SELECT DISTINCT connected_stops.stop_id`".

To make performance acceptable you'll want to create indices on `stop_times.stop_id` and `stop_times.trip_id`:

```
CREATE INDEX stop_times_stop_id_index ON stop_times(stop_id);

CREATE INDEX stop_times_trip_id_index ON stop_times(trip_id);
```

But if you're developing an online application, this is probably not the way to go. You'd be better off precalculating connections between stops using a graph representation of the transit network in memory and then querying *that* at runtime.

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm! `stop_sequence` did the trick :) I'm just playing around and building some proof of concepts, so this one won't be used in an real online application.